# Calling MySQL stored routines more than once in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to call *multiple* MySQL stored routines *sequentially* with PHP, but I can only call *a single* one successfully---after that I get the error **Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now**. Researching the problem I found it's a common headache (caused by not "finishing up" the previous call before the next one is made), but I didn't find a solution I could apply to my code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i+=1) 
{
    if (!($conn=getconn() && ($result=mysql_query("call MyStoredRoutine();", $conn))))
    {
        $errorMessage = mysql_error($conn); // Error 2nd time here...
    }
    else {
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            // Retrieve data here...
        }
    }
}
```

And the implementation of `getconn()` (I don't think it's relevant but you never know):

```
function getconn() {
    global $custdb, $custdb_connection, $dbuser, $dbpass;
    if (! $custdb_connection) {
        if (! ($custdb_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", $dbuser, $dbpass, true))) return false;
        if (! (@ mysql_select_db($custdb, $custdb_connection)))  return false;
    }
    return $custdb_connection;
}
```

PHP version is *5.3.8-1~dotdeb.1*, MySQL is *5.1.54-1ubuntu4*.

Anybody knows what I should do to my code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe switch to MySQLi and use [`multi-query()`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

MySQLi gives you the added benefit of prepared statements and is build to support OOP.

Comment: That's one of the things I read when researching. However, I don't know how much trouble it is switching to MySQLi. If there's an easier solution to the problem, I would prefer that.

Comment: I think you should switch the problem around: How much trouble will it cause in the future if you do not switch while you can?
There is a tremendous benefit in using prepared statements and OOP. (common libraries that support prepared statements in PHP are both MySQLi and PDO).

Comment: Guess you're right. Thanks for setting my head straight. :-) So, calling two stored routines is simply impossible with my current approach?

Comment: As far as I know, PHP's mysql_* functions do not allow multiple queries/calls to be made in a single function call.

Comment: You just need to close the result set in order to release resources before calling the next stored procedure, so call `$result->close()` before you call the next sproc and you should be fine.  That doesn't mean you shouldn't switch to MySQLi.  I'm sure you should, but that's a separate issue.  MySQLi isn't going to let you call multiple stored procedures _concurrently_, either, unless it is opening multiple connections to the database.